# Get all string in one variable after space in javascript

Tags: javascript

what i am doing

for example i have a name

```js
 var nameofuser = 'John Constantine vayo';
    var values = nameofuser.split(" ");
    var f_name = values[0];
    var l_name = nameofuser.substr(nameofuser.indexOf(' ') + 1);
    console.log(f_name);
    console.log(l_name);
```

it is working fine when user entering his last name and other title or so on, it is all going in l_name but when a user enterned only first name like only 'John' then l_name is also populated with 'john' :(,

i want IF a user type last name and so on then only l_name should be populated.

if user type only first name then only f_name with first name should be populated

Comment: What result do you want ?

Comment: if a user type last name and so on then only l_name should be populated. if user type only first name then only f_name with first name should be populated

Comment: It sounds like you want a script that recognizes whether a single word is a first name or a last name. How is it supposed to do that?

Comment: Check for the `values.length`

Comment: after first space everything should be in second variable

Comment: @adasdasd And if there is no space at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var nameofuser = 'John Constantine vayo';
var values = nameofuser.split(" ");
var f_name = values[0];
var l_name = values[1] ? nameofuser.substr(nameofuser.indexOf(' ') + 1) : '';
console.log(f_name);
console.log(l_name);
```

Comment: If it works then please upvote my answer and check this as right answer @adasdasd

Comment: @Gauravjoshi You can look into `values.join(' ')` for `l_name`

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are the usual tool for this kind of decomposition:

```
var nameofuser = str.match(/^\s*(\S+)\s*(.*?)\s*$/).slice(1);
```

`'John Constantine vayo'` gives `["John", "Constantine vayo"]`

and `'John'` gives `["John"]`.

But be careful of this kind of guesses. In a multicultural world it's safer to just take what the user provides.

Comment: I approve of this, but it might break if the string begins with a space. You just need to trim the string before matching it.

Comment: @alebianco I tuned the regex to do the trimming

Answer (score 1):

When searching for a space over a string that doesn't have a space `-1` would be returned. So -1 + 1 will be evaluated to 0 and the substring is returning the entire string.

```
var nameofuser = 'John Constantine vayo';
var values = nameofuser.split(" ");
var f_name = values.shift();
var l_name = values.length ? values.join(" ") : undefined;
console.log(f_name);
console.log(l_name);
```

Comment: You can skip ternary operation. Split will always return you an array of at least 1 value. Just use `values.shift()` for first name, and `values.join(' ')` for lastname

Comment: This will give you `John` and `Constantine` only. l_name should be `Constantine vayo`. You can check my answer, as I have already done that.

Comment: @Rajesh Yeah. I hope the current edit would address the issue that you were talking about.

Answer (score 0):

It Is because You have to make sure there is more than one word for that line:

> `var l_name = nameofuser.substr(nameofuser.indexOf(' ') + 1);`

Your code should look something like this:

```
var nameofuser = 'John Constantine vayo';
var values = nameofuser.split(" ");
var f_name = values[0];
var l_name = (values.length > 1) ? nameofuser.substr(nameofuser.indexOf(' ') + 1) : '';
console.log(f_name);
console.log(l_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `.indexOf()`, if value is not matches, you will get index as `-1` so `indexOf() + 1` would interpret as `-1 + 1 = 0`. So you end up doing `namesofuser.substring(0)`

Try something like this:

#### string.split + array.shift and array.join

```js
function getNames(str) {
  var values = str.split(" ");
  var f_name = values.shift();
  var l_name = values.join(' ');
  console.log(f_name);
  console.log(l_name);
}

getNames('John Constantine vayo')
getNames("Foo")
```

#### string.substring

```js
function getNames(str) {
  var index = str.indexOf(' ');
  index = index > -1 ? index : str.length;
  var f_name = str.substring(0, index);
  var l_name = str.substring(index + 1);
  console.log(f_name);
  console.log(l_name);
}

getNames('John Constantine vayo')
getNames("Foo")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if there is more than one word in the values array?
Hope this helps :)

```js
var values = nameofuser.split(" ");
var f_name = values[0];
if (values.lenght >= 2) {
  var l_name = nameofuser.substr(nameofuser.indexOf(' ') + 1);
} else { //let lastname empty or do something else}

  console.log(f_name);
  console.log(l_name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var nameofuser = 'john';
var f_name = '';
var l_name ='';
var values = nameofuser.split(" ");
var f_name = values[0];
if(values.length > 1){
     var l_name = nameofuser.substr(nameofuser.indexOf(' ') +1);
  }       
console.log(f_name);
console.log(l_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

this works as well and fixes the problems you'll have if `nameofuser` begins with a space

```
var nameofuser = 'John Constantine vayo';
var values = nameofuser.trim().split(" ");
var f_name = values[0];
var l_name = values.slice(1).join(" ")
console.log(f_name);
console.log(l_name);
```